# Loop through interfaces defined in the file

Tags: typescript, interface, ts-node

I have a code that suppose to loop through my `interfaces.ts` file that has defined interfaces like that:

```
export interface Users {
  name: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
}
```

here is my code

```
import * as types from './interfaces';
console.log(types); // always = {}
for (const interfaceName in types) {
  if (types.hasOwnProperty(interfaceName)) {
    const interfaceType = types[interfaceName];
    func(interfaceType, interfaceName, outputFilePath);
  }
}
```

However `types` is always `{}`. Is there anyway to fix?

what I am trying to do is to use interfaces to generate template based on interface properties names and its type

Comment: Once TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript, interfaces are lost.

Comment: @pzaenger right, is there any work around?

Comment: what I am trying to do is to use interfaces to generate template based on interface properties names and its type

Comment: Alternatively instead of interfaces you could use classes.

Comment: @Mathyn I need to keep it as interfaces...also I am using ts-node unless it not making any difference.

Comment: You could use zod to define your interfaces and then you'd have something manipulatable during runtime, too.